# How to undo changes made from script on contenteditable div

Tags: html, editor, contenteditable, undo

Let's have contenteditable div. Browser itself manage undo on it.
But when additional content changes (or touching selection ranges) are made from script (in addition to user action) then it stops behave as user expected.

In other words when user hit Ctrl+Z then div content is not reverted to previous state.

See following simplified artificial example:

https://codepen.io/farin/pen/WNEMVEB

```
const editor = document.getElementById("editor")
editor.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {  
  if (ev.key === 'a') {
    const sel = window.getSelection()
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    const node = range.startContainer;
    const value = node.nodeValue       
    node.nodeValue = value + 'aa'        
    range.setStart(node, value.length + 2)
    range.setEnd(node, value.length + 2)
    ev.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

All written 'a' letters are doubled.

Undo is ok as long as there is no 'a' typed.
When user typed 'a' (appended to text as double 'aa') and hits Ctrl+Z, then he expects  both 'a' will be removed and cursor moves back to original position.

Instead only one 'a' is reverted on undo and second one added by script remain.

If event is also prevented by preventDefault() (which is not needed in this example, but in my real world example i can hardly avoid it) then all is worse.
Because undo reverts previous user action.

I could images that whole undo/redo stuff will be managed by script, but it means implementation of whole undo/redo logic. That's too complicated, possible fragile and with possible many glitches.

Instead I would like tell browser something like that there is atomic change which should be reverted by one user undo. Is this possible?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but, in my experience, trying to build a robust user experience with raw contenteditable divs is a rabbit hole of problems - you're hitting one of them, but there are probably dozens more that you might not even know about yet. I'd recommend giving up and using a library like `quill` or `draft.js`.

Comment: @AndrewStegmaier I am currently using quill. I my case need no toolbar. 
Only custom manipulations are there, impemented as quill plugins. It faces some limitations of quill and I considering using pure content editable div. I have proof of concept, there manipulation works better implemented directly, only issue is undo/redo. 
(my use usecase is similar to post creatin on facebook or twiitter, few rich content (fb has mention, twitter has links)

Comment: @AndrewStegmaier in other words, i would never want to build own full feature editor. but in this specific case, i am not sure. With quill, i am facing some annoying glitches and api limitation (like I can update content ex post, wchich makes visible delay for user)

Comment: @AndrewStegmaier you were right :) But the right solution in my case seems to be TipTap. Really like it's versatile and simple interface. So eventually it becomes migration from Quill to TipTap. it solves my issues with Quill and avoid hell with plain content editable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the "revisions" in an array, then push the `innerHTML` of the `div` to it whenever you programmatically change the `innerHTML` of it.

Then, you can set the `innerHTML` of the div to the last item in the revisions array whenever the user uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut.

```js
const previousRevisions = []

function saveState() {
  previousRevisions.push(editor.innerHTML)
}

function undoEdit() {
  if (previousRevisions.length > 0) {
    editor.innerHTML = previousRevisions.pop();
  }
}

const editor = document.getElementById("editor")

editor.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {
  if (ev.key === 'a') {
    saveState()
    const sel = window.getSelection()
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    const node = range.startContainer;
    const value = node.nodeValue
    node.nodeValue = value + 'a'
    range.setStart(node, value.length + 1)
    range.setEnd(node, value.length + 1)
  } else if (ev.ctrlKey && ev.key == 'z') {
    undoEdit()
  }
})
```

```css
#editor{width:600px;min-height:250px;border:1px solid black;font-size:24px;margin:0 auto;padding:10px;font-family:monospace;word-break:break-all}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">type here&nbsp;</div>
```

The benefit of this solution is that it will not conflict with the browser's native <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut behavior.

Comment: looks like way to go (with some enhancements like saving also caret position ... etc)

Answer (score -1):

Make the parent a div (if it isn't) and make it so it adds spans inside of it every time the user taps a so the new span and set it's id to `span-keyword` will have `aa` as the value / text. Then check if the users cursor is at the beginning of it and check if there is no other text in-front of it and the user did no other action in it. If there is no text and no other actions happened do this:

```
document.getElementById('span-keyword').remove();
```